# Process substitution under the hood

Tags: bash, process

This question is from https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution

```
mkfifo /var/tmp/fifo1
mkfifo /var/tmp/fifo2
sort list1 >/var/tmp/fifo1 &
sort list2 >/var/tmp/fifo2 &
diff /var/tmp/fifo1 /var/tmp/fifo2
rm /var/tmp/fifo1 /var/tmp/fifo2
```

As I understand about named pipes, I'm thinking the following is in effect:

On lines 1-2, we create two named pipes: fifo1 and fifo2.

`sort list1 > fifo1 &` and `sort list2 > fifo2 &` are trying to write to the named pipes so they are blocked until something reads from them.

Then `diff` command that comes afterwards, reads from fifo1 and fifo2. So lines 3-4 are unblocked. Next `diff` is executed and the output sent to terminal.

Lastly, we delete named pipes fifo1 and fifo2.

The source says all this is the same as `diff <(sort list1) <(sort list2)`.

Is my explanation correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it looks correct to me. `diff` expects files, and process substitution allows you to turn the output of the two `sort` commands into files.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my explanation correct?

No. The `sort`s are blocked before even being started (the subshells which would execute the `sort`s are blocked when trying to *open* the fifos). And they're only blocked until the other side of the fifo is *opened* too, no need to *read* anything from it.

If you try `mkfifo /tmp/fifo; true > /tmp/fifo`, the `true` will be blocked, even if it isn't ever trying to write anything to the fifo. A `true < /tmp/fifo` from another shell will unblock it, without trying to *read* anything at all.

> The source says all this is the same as `diff <(sort list1) <(sort list2)`.

It's not. If for some reason `diff fifo1 fifo2` terminates before opening the fifos passed as arguments, the `sort ... &` will stay there forever, until someone has mercy and manually kills them.

And I don't know if process substitution can really be implemented with named pipes, but FWIW bash is NOT getting there by a stretch; on platforms without `/dev/fd`s, bash's process substitutions are buggy and only usable with very much care.